# JSON returns all NULL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to get a JSON from a MySQL database, but it does not recover anything. Here my code:

db_config.php

```
<?php

/*
 * All database connection variables
 */

define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "biblioapp"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
?>
```

db_connect

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT{

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

get_products_details.php

```
<?php
```

$response = array();

```
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
$search = '';
    if (isset($_POST['search'])){
        $search = strtolower($_POST['search']);

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registres WHERE titol LIKE '%".$search."%' OR autor LIKE '%".$search."%'");


    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["id"] = $result["id"];
            $product["titol"] = $result["titol"];
            $product["autor"] = $result["autor"];
            $product["descripcion"] = $result["descripcion"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

get_all_products.php

```
<?php

   // array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM registres") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["registres"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["id"] = $result["id"];
        $product["titol"] = $result["titol"];
        $product["autor"] = $result["autor"];
        $product["descripcion"] = $result["descripcion"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["registres"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

If I go to localhost/json/get_product_details.php I receive this:

```
{"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}
```

If i go to localhost/json/get_all_products.php I receive this:

```
{"registres":[{"id":null,"titol":null,"autor":null,"descripcion":null},{"id":null,"titol":null,"autor":null,"descripcion":null},{"id":null,"titol":null,"autor":null,"descripcion":null},{"id":null,"titol":null,"autor":null,"descripcion":null},{"id":null,"titol":null,"autor":null,"descripcion":null}],"success":1}
```

What's wrong here? Thanks...

Comment: So `$_POST['search']` is not set. This looks like some very strange kind of duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149404/parse-error-syntax-error-in-php-json-code#comment46520862_29149404

Comment: I just looking for a little help with the code, I have been trying to create a JSON file in different ways and this was the closest to getting results, it seems a simple process but I have always errors o no response from system, so I ask review if I overlooked something, nothing more.

Comment: Like I said, the problem with `get_products_details.php` is what I mentioned in my first comment, it is not related to the database or JSON.

Comment: And can you tell me a little more explained what should I do? I'm new to all this, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $product = array();
    $product["id"] = $result["id"];
```

Your results are not in `$result`, but in `$row` :

```
$product["id"] = $row["id"];
```

Comment: With this I receive the id's, but the other camps are null.
It's the first time that I'm working with JSON, thanks for the help

Comment: @Santiago Well, you also have to use `$row` for the other variables : `$row['titol'], $row[.....`

Comment: I've tried it before, but I received this message:
Notice: Undefined index: descripcion in E:\xampp\htdocs\json\get_all_products.php on line 31
Without descripcion variable only shows a white page.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing common with json in your issue :-)

The only problem you have - empty values in array you've created.

You didn't give us any information about table structure you have, and values you are trying to debug.

So just a quick fix to start better debugging could be:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      $response["registres"][] = $row;
 }
```

but reviewing your code I want to suggest you to stop using deprecated mysql_ calls. Use mysqli or PDO.